# How can I Set the Order on Items in a Chart Legend?

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-sheets-charts

I have these two charts which pull the same data from the same table. The legend items appear in reverse order in the second chart. Anyone know how to make those match?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Google Sheets, the order of the chart legend is based on the order of Series added to the chart. To reorder the legend, edit the chart and remove all series. Add the series back in the order that you'd like to see them displayed.

**Note:** On some charts (notably the "stacked" varieties), you have to add the series in *reverse order* to get the desired result.

[image: Stacked Column Chart with series order mapped to legend]